# overflow: hidden; image scrollBy

Tags: javascript, button, html, scroll, overflow

I had an idea for like a bus window as a fixed frame, about 800px wide, with a parallax city with the content on billboards spaced out so when you scroll between them it allows the parallax to look like bus is moving. The content will be much bigger than the window like a sprite and I'll put forward and back buttons that will scrollBy (x amount, 0). I have a working parallax script and a rough cityscape of 3 layers that all work fine.

I have hit a wall. I am trying to clear a scrollBy animation after it scrolls 1000px. Then you click it again and it goes another 1000px. This is my function.

```
function scrollForward() {
    window.scrollBy(5,0);
    scrollLoop = setInterval('scrollForward()',10);
}
```

So far I can only clear it when it gets to 1000. I tried doing 1000 || 2000 ect but after the first one it goes really fast and won't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your asking here. Perhaps you could provide more relevant code?

I do see a potential issue with your code. You call `setInterval('scrollForward()', 10)` which will cause `scrollForward` to be called every 10ms. However, each of those calls to `scrollForward` will create *more* intervals to `scrollForward` creating a sort of explosion of recursion. You probably want to use `setTimeout` or create your interval outside of this function.

Also, as an aside you can change your code to simply: `setInterval(scrollForward, 10)`. Removing the quotes and the parens makes it a littler easier to read and manager. You can even put complex, lambda functions like:

```
setInterval(function() {
   scrollForward();
   // do something else
 }, 10);
```

**edit:**
So if you know that scrollForward moves the item 10px, and you want it to stop after it moves the item 1000px, then you simply need to stop it has moved that much. I still don't know how your code is actually structured, but it might look something like the following:

```
(function() {
  var moved_by = 0;
  var interval = null;

  var scrollForward = function() {
     // move by 10px
     moved_by += 10;
     if (moved_by === 1000 && interval !== null) {
        clearInterval(interval);
     }
  };

  var interval = setInterval(scrollForward, 10);
})();
```

If you want to clear it after 1000 or 2000, you simply adjust the `if` statement accordingly. I hope that helps.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example of how it might work. If you post more of your code, I can comment better.

Answer (score 0):

Excelsior https://stackoverflow.com/users/66580/majid-fouladpour wrote a great piece of code for someone else with a different question. It wasn't quite right for what the other guy wanted but it is perfect for me.

```
function scrollForward() {
    var scrolledSoFar = 0;
    var scrollStep = 75;
    var scrollEnd  = 1000;
    var timerID = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollBy(scrollStep, 0);
        scrolledSoFar += scrollStep;
        if( scrolledSoFar >= scrollEnd ) clearInterval(timerID);
    }, 10);
}

function scrollBack() {
    var scrolledSoFar = 0;
    var scrollStep = -75;
    var scrollEnd  = -1000;
    var timerID = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollBy(scrollStep, 0);
        scrolledSoFar += scrollStep;
        if( scrolledSoFar <= scrollEnd ) clearInterval(timerID);
    }, 10);
}
```

Now for step two figuring out how to put this content animation behind a frame.